# How to make a function that calculates a chance of input based on some factors

Tags: python, function, math

I am currently in the process of creating a game in python, which is basically the same as the game "The Button" on steam.

Whenever you click, there is an n% chance of resetting back down to n being 0.

Whenever you click, n increases by 1.

This means if n was 20, there is a 20% chance of it resetting on that particular click.

Using this information, I want to create a function that returns the total chance of an input from happening.

For example, an input of "10" might return "1.65", as in a 65% chance of it resetting (including the 1%, 2% and so on that came before)

Any ideas are welcome (i am fearing for my sanity over this)

The only solution I had thought of was this:

```
highestnum = int(input())
def calcchance(n):
    nums = []
    totalchance = 1
    for count in range(n+1):
        nums.append(1+(count/100))
    for count2 in range(len(nums)):
        totalchance = totalchance * nums[count2]
    return totalchance
totalchance = calcchance(highestnum)
```

but that returns numbers above 2.00, representing chances of above 100% (1.00 = 0%, 1.50 = 50%, so on), which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hello. Welcome! Why 1.65 and not 0.65? Why the +1 ?

Comment: That's a good point! I think because when I timesed them together, I would lay it out like "1 X 1.01 X 1.02.." because if it started at 0 that would mean it would just times to 0.

Comment: Good observation. Actually it should be 1 x 0.99 x 0.98 x ... , like in JonSG 's answer.

Comment: Well, the chance of **not** resetting is 1 x 0.99 x 0.98 x .... The chance of resetting cannot be calculated directly easily, so it's best to calculate the chance of not resetting first, and then use chance_of_reset = 1 - chance_of_not_reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If at any given button press `n` there is a `n%` chance of reset, then I think you can calculate the cumulative chance of net resetting after n presses as:

```py
def chance_of_having_reset(n):
    chance_of_not_reset = 1.0
    for i in range(1, n):
        chance_of_not_reset *= (100 - i) / 100
    return 1.0 - chance_of_not_reset
```